# Need to connect Tridion core service for .Net Core 3.1 Application

Tags: web8.5, core-service, .net

Requirement is to create a Core service application on the .Net Core 3.1 framework for Web 8.5 version.

Tried the below steps as suggested in the blog.
[Blog](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/tridion-contentmanager-coreservice-client-with-net-core)

1. Add new Connected Services
2. Select Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider.
3. Update the core service link
   https://tridionCmsServer/webservices/CoreService201603.svc
4. Selected the below displayed "CoreService201603" and updated the namespace
5. Selected reuse types in referenced assemblies
6. Access level for generated classes: -> Public
7. Finish

Window with status as Adding connected service to project is displayed.

Then below errors are displayed.

Failed: See window for error details.
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
- The following 'Microsoft.NetCore.App', version "2.1.0" was not found.
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
3.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
The specified framework can be foundat:
Done.

Do we have any workaround to connect the core service for .NetCore 3.1 or solution to fix this issue.

Please let us know, since this is a blocker for us to migrate our whole application to this new framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect to the Core Service in a Web 8.5 instance from a .NET Core 3.1 web application. Here are some pointers that might help you connect to the Core Service using a .NET Core web application:

1. The version of the .NET Core runtime and SDK installed on the machine running the web application should be 3.1. You can check the version by running the command `dotnet --version` in the terminal. You should be seeing 3.1. If you have installed .NET Core, but not seeing the right version in the terminal, ensure that the .NET runtime is added `PATH` variable.  More information about how to check which versions are installed is available [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows).

[image]

2. In the web application's property `.csproj` file, the target framework should be set `netcoreapp3.1`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you have the right .NET runtime and SDK installed and if the web application is configured to use the right .NET runtime, you should be to hit the route `/getapiversion` and get the API version by following the steps as described by Robert [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/20421/1587).

[image]