# How do I retrieve an entity from CMS from an External Library Connector

Tags: core-service, ecl-connector

Edit: I realize, I never included which version of Tridion is being used. We are using 9.1

Currently my connector is using API calls to an external content library to get lists of folders and files back and creates entities for them.

When trying to access a file through the CMS, it takes the Identity and uses it to get the file from the ECL to recreate the fileEntity it returns to the user.

Currently the fileEntity is being called for and created twice. There's a lot of problems with this approach, including not being able to make changes on the CMS Entity without being overwritten when the Entity gets recreated next time it is accessed.

**What I'm looking for** is how to have the Connector target an entity from the CMS so I can read its properties and make updates to it instead of making a new one each time I need to access it.

**What I've tried**
I've tried using the CoreServices.Client Package for its GetList and GetListXml functions, but the Tridion Integration Framework the Connector is based on is built using netstandard2.0 and the CoreServices Package gives me this warning when importing it through NuGet:

warning NU1701: Package 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

I fixed a few dependance issues that arose in order to build and test it, but I ran into runtime errors which I think stemmed from not using .NetFramework.

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange can you please provide the Tridion version that you are using and what templating are you using .

Comment: I am using the template described here in this post: https://docs.sdl.com/783502/741537/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/creating-a-connector-using-the-tridion-connector-template

Comment: The purpose of a Connector is to get/set content in an external system. It is not clear to me why you want the Connector to access CM. Can you clarify?

Answer (score -1):

Generally .NET Core and .NET Framework are incompatible. The custom connector built using the Tridion Connector Template is .NET Core, while the Core Service package you are trying to install is built on .NET Framework. To use the Core Service API on the custom connector, you can add Tridion Core Service WCF URL as a service reference to the custom connector and that way you would be able to the use the `GetList` and `GetListXml` functions.

Your solution should like the image below if you had added the Core Service WCF URL as a service reference and you make a connection to the Core Service as you would normally do on a .NET Framework project.

[image]

This great answer by Robert is what I used for reference: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/20421/1587.